# sort a file by grouping column

Tags: sorting, multiple-columns

I have a file like the following:

PSG1    B41M    3

PSG1    G03G    1

PSG1    C09D    2

PSG2    H01L    4

PSG2    C08L    3

PSG10   H01B    2

PSG10   C08J    4

I want to sort the values in the third column but only when they have the same PSG.
For the given example, I want the output file:

PSG1    B41M    3

PSG1    C09D    2

PSG1    G03G    1

PSG2    H01L    4

PSG2    C08L    3

PSG10   C08J    4

PSG10   H01B    2

I tried to sort the file based on the first and third column using command sort but it does not work as PSG10 appears exactly after PSG1 (before PSG2).

Any other ideas? I do not care if it is a script or Java code

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Map<K, V> data structure to hold data and sort on the values then you can have a reference [how to sort a Map<K, V>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)